How to Pass Parameters to Airflow DAG from UI in the Latest Version 2.8.2
Earlier we are using Airflow V2.5.0. In this version we can pass parameters to Airflow DAG in the form of key values by choosing the Trigger DAG w/config option in trigger button in the Airflow UI.

Now we upgraded the Airflow Version to 2.8.2.In the upgraded version I couldn't see that option(w/config) while triggering the DAG. It seems like it is removed in the latest version.
I know we can pass the parameters using CLI but my use case is I need to pass parameters through Airflow UI only.
Could someone please let me know know how to pass parameters in the latest Airflow version 2.8 from Airflow UI.
Thank You.
I tried to trigger Airflow DAG manually with parameters but I didn't see the option to pass parameters in the latest Airflow UI. I am expecting an option to pass parameters to DAG while triggering it manually in the Airflow UI
